# Código de sequência de números retorna a soma incorreta de números C#

Tags: c#

Criei um código que coleta uma sequência de números inteiros que só acaba quando o número zero seja digitado. Ao final imprimir a soma dos números está de maneira errada onde sempre está um número a menos que o esperado.

```
Digite um número: 1
Digite um número: 2
Digite um número: 3
Digite um número: 0
A média dos número é 5 // Era pra ser 6
```

O código:

```
using System;

namespace TesteRepeticao1
{
    class Program4
    {
        static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            int somanumero = 0, numero;
            Console.Write("Digite um número: ");
            numero = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            do
            {
                if (numero != 0)
                {
                    Console.Write("Digite um número: ");
                    numero = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    somanumero += numero;
                }
            } while (numero != 0);
            Console.Write($"A soma dos número é {somanumero}");
            Console.ReadKey();
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Antes do `do` precisa somar o primeiro número, senão ele é perdido ao executar o `ReadLine()` dentro do laço:

```
numero = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
somanumero += numero;
do
{
 .... resto do código
```

Comment: Resolvido o problema, agora sim ele volta o resultado desejado.

Answer (score 2):

Uma maneira de realizar essa tarefa é realizar a primeira soma antes de realizar as repetições:

```
using System;

namespace TesteRepeticao1
{
    class Program4
    {
        static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            int somanumero = 0, numero;
            Console.Write("Digite um número: ");
            numero = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            if (numero != 0)
                somaNumero = numero; //assim você já guarda o valor dessa primeira iteração com o usuário
            do
            {
                if (numero != 0)
                {
                    Console.Write("Digite um número: ");
                    numero = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    somanumero += numero;
                }
            } while (numero != 0);
            Console.Write($"A soma dos número é {somanumero}");
            Console.ReadKey();
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Eu criaria uma variável global para receber a soma, faria as operações dentro do loop e ao final exibiria o valor da variável global, tirando aquela condição, pois se o valor for zero ele não vai alterar a soma e o loop será finalizado.

```
using System;

namespace TesteRepeticao1
{
    class Program4
    {
        static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            int somanumero = 0, numero;
            do
            {
                Console.Write("Digite um número: ");
                numero = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                somanumero += numero;

            } while (numero != 0);
            Console.Write($"A soma dos número é {somanumero}");
            Console.ReadKey();
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```